# Git Extensions - how to merge master into branch

Tags: git, git-extensions

How can I use Git Extensions to merge the master branch into a feature branch?
Is it possible to use the GitExtensions GUI only, or using the `git shell` is the preferred way to do it?

Answer (score 9):

> How can I use Git Extensions to merge the master branch into a feature branch?

- Checkout the **feature branch**, because that's the branch you want to update (one of the main rules of using git)
- right click on the `master` branch. You should see a `merge into` menu item in the contextual menu that just opened.
- done